# LINQ in ASP.Net Core: conversion fails in left join

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I am running Visual Studio 2019; ASP.Net Core 2.1.

I am working on an internal device reservation web app for a client. I am getting a strange exception message:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'False' to data type int

I have ruled out the `select new CalendarData` section by commenting out the various assignments in different chunks. I have ruled out the `where` clause in a similar way, commenting out the the filters one at a time.

```
try {
    reservations = (
        from reservation in reservationsContext.Reservations
        join reservationToBgColor in reservationsContext.ReservationToBgColor
            on new {
                id = reservation.Id,
                user = admin ? myUserName : ""
            } equals new {
                id = reservationToBgColor.ReservationId,
                user = reservationToBgColor.AdminNetid.Trim().ToLower()
            } into resColorBucket
        from resColor in resColorBucket.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where reservation.Device.ToUpper().Split(
                  '.',
                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
              )[0].Trim().Equals(myMachine)
              && reservation.StartDate < myEnd
              && reservation.EndDate >= myStart
        select new CalendarData {
            ...
        }
    ).ToList();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception(e.Message);
}
```

That leaves the "left join".  Specifically it is the

```
    user = admin ? myUserName : ""
```

in the first clause.  The contents of this line are:

- user: string in the anonymous object being built
- admin: bool, a variable external to the query that marks if the caller of the method is an "admin" or not.
- myUserName: string, a variable external to the query that is either empty or has a username in it.

Why is anything being converted to int? What am I missing?

Comment: Did your try moving the ternary operator outside the linq query? You said both `admin` and `myUserName` are external variable, so you should be able to compute `user` outside the query.

Comment: Had that thought as I was leaving the building.  Just tried it and that was the key.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `admin` field is not actually a Boolean but a string. Because of this, you cannot use it in a ternary expression like the one you are  doing. Either make sure that the field is bool or simply quick fix this code using `admin == "True"` instead. I recommend the first fix :)

Comment: It is definitely declared as a `bool` in the parameter list to the method.  I ended up moving the operation out of the join and just putting in the result of the ternary op.